# Python: Make one HTTP request for a list of URL and store the XML files in a tar.gz

Tags: python, xml, http, request, urllib2

I'm quite new at using python for http request and so far I have a script
that is fetching XML files from a long list of URL's (on the same server) to then extract data from nodes with lxml.
Everything works fine however i'm a bit concern about the huge number of request the host server might receive from me.

Is there a way using "request" to send only one request to the server that will fetch all the XML from the different URL and store them in a tar.gz file?

Here what is doing my script so far (with a small sample):

```
IDlist = list(accession_clean)
URLlist = ['http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q13111.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2A2F0.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/G5EA09.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q8IY37.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/O14545.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/O00308.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q13136.xml', 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q86UT6.xml']

for id, item in zip(IDlist, URLlist):
    try:
       textfile = urllib2.urlopen(item);
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
       print("URL", item, "could not be read.")
       continue
    try:
       tree = etree.parse(textfile);
    except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError:
       print 'Skipping invalid XML from URL {}'.format(item)
       continue
```

Answer (score 2):

That website offers an API which is documented [here](http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access), although it will not give you a tar.gz file, it is possible to retrieve multiple entries with a single HTTP request.

Perhaps one of the [batch](http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access#batch_retrieval_of_entries) or [query](http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access#retrieving_entries_via_queries) methods will work for you.